# What will this command do: p4 sync //depot/proj1/

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am new to Perforce and want to create a automated tool to get the latest revision by itself. I have a mapping like this:

```
P4CLIENT: Proj_name 
Worspace root direcctory: C:\...\Proj_name  
Stream: Build
```

Now  what i desire is it should get latest revision of all files from:

```
Build\fold1\fold2   to    C:\...\Proj_name\fold1\fold2
```

When I just ran `p4 sync command`, it copied all files from `Build   to   C:\...\Proj_name`.

So please tell how to specify the folder path from where to get the latest revision. Will the command `p4 sync //depot/proj1/...` work for me and how does it change in my condition ?

Comment: Assuming that `//depot/proj1/...` maps to a location in your client, then `p4 sync //depot/proj1/...` will sync those files.  It's not quite clear what you're asking.  If you want to change where those files are synced to, run `p4 client` to change the depot-to-client mappings.

Comment: @jamesdlin It is simple:
Suppose I have mapped a/b to c/d but now I want to get latest revision from a/b/e/f to c/d/e/f/. How to achieve this from command line.

Comment: If your current directory is at the root of your Perforce client, `p4 sync c/d/...` will sync everything under `c/d`and give you `c/d/e/f`.  Or you can do `p4 sync //depot/a/b/...`.

Comment: @jamesdlin is there any command for getting Client name and Client root.

Comment: As I already mentioned, run `p4 client`.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `View:` section of your client spec to describe which parts of the overall repository you wish to work with, and where those files should be placed on your workstation's filesystem.

In your particular case, to specify the folder path, as well as where those files should be placed, you might specify your `View:` as something like:

```
View:
    //depot/Build/fold1/fold2/...  //Proj_name/fold1/fold2/...
```

You may have considerably more complex view mappings; the view syntax is quite powerful. To learn more about view mappings, type `p4 help views`.

After you change your `View:` specification for your client, run:

```
p4 sync
```

The `sync` command will notice that you have changed your view mapping, and it will re-arrange the files in the root of your client on your workstation, so that they are arranged as described by your new view mapping.

If you don't wish to sync your **entire** client, you can specify a subset of the files which should be sync'd, by naming that subset of files using a file pattern as an argument to the `sync` command:

```
p4 sync //depot/Build/fold1/fold2/*.cpp
```

However, that can be quite confusing, and I recommend that, to start, you avoid using that advanced usage, and stick to performing a `p4 sync` with no file arguments, at least until you get more comfortable with how `p4 sync` is used. For one thing, when you are sync'ing different subsets of files with different file arguments, it is quite easy to get your workstation's filesystem into an un-buildable state, by getting half of the files from one changelist and half from another, which will cause you to have code that doesn't compile, etc.

So, for now:

1. Consider which parts of the repository you wish to work with, and where you want them to go on your workstation's filesystem
2. Run `p4 client` and describe the appropriate `View:` line(s) to specify those files, using the pattern-matching syntax of the `View:` field
3. Run `p4 sync` and Perforce will put those files on your computer as specified.

Comment: In the 2nd step, "Run p4 client and describe the appropriate View" do I need to manually change the view. Isn't there any command for this?

Comment: Can you please also tell commands to get the Client root and Client name and Client Stream.  I couldn't find them in command reference.